# How to use some ngActivityIndicator on page?

Tags: angularjs, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I use Angular JS [library](https://github.com/voronianski/ngActivityIndicator) to display preloader during is loaded content from AJAX response.

In tutorial tells about using some preloaders on page based on $scope model.
But it does not work for me:

```
<div ng-show="myLoadingConditional" ng-activity-indicator skip-ng-show="yes"></div>
```

Can you share a right way using?